# Lookup data using two criteria from a data frame containing stock data using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two Excel tables. The first (InitData) contains stock names, purchase dates and purchase prices. The second (HistData) contains historical price data for the stocks. Each stock has its own tab (sheet).

I am trying to find the date and price of the stocks in HistData when they first exceed a 10% price increase from the initial purchase date.

I can read both sheets into Python with no problem. But I am completely lost on setting the criteria to find the StkName, Date, and price,

Here's what I have so far:

Reading the data in:

```
{HistData = pd.read excel(C:'\....HistData.xlsx',sheet_name=None) #each stock has its own sheet.
HistData = pd.read excel(C:'\....InitData.xlsx')}




{For i in range (len(InitData)):
    StkName = InitData.iloc[i,0]
    PurDate = InitData.iloc[i,1]
    PurPrice = InitData.iloc[i,2]}

    {For j in range(len(HistData)):}
 
    [For each StkName, cycle through the HistData dataframe and return the date (which must be greater than the purchase date) and price (which should be greater than the purchase price by 10% or more). I can't figure out how to tie the StkName, date criteria (>pur date), and price criteria (10% or more increase over pur price) all together.

HistData

Stk1 (tab name)            Stk2 (tab name)

Date          Price        Date              Price
06/10/23      10           07/15/2022        18
06/15/23      10.20        07/16/2022        14
06/23/23      11           09/20/2022        17
06/30/23      12           09/30/2022        17.60


Init Data (all on one tab)

    Stk      Pur Date    PurPrice
    Stk1     06/15/2023  10.20
    Stk2     07/16/2022  14

Expected Output:

Stk            Price Goal Date          Price
Stk1           06/30/2023                12
Stk2           09/20/2022                17
```